# Rails custom text on submit button using variable from partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form inside a partial named `_configuration_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @configuration, url: admin_config_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :chars %>
  <%= f.number_field :chars %>
  <%= f.submit @submit_text %>
<% end %>
```

where I'm passing in `@configuration` and `@submit_text` as local variables into the partial, as follows:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/admin/configuration_form',
           :locals => {@configuration => :configuration, @submit_text => "Update configurations"} %>
```

The `@configuration` variable appears to be working properly as it is drawing the data from the controller. However, the submit button is showing the default text, as per rails defaults.

My question is: am I doing something wrong here to prevent the desired custom button text from appearing, or is there a way to enforce the use of a local variable? I also tried using `"#{@submit_text}"` which just showed an empty button (no text at all). Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax for passing locals into a partial is:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/admin/configuration_form',
           :locals => {configuration: @configuration, submit_text: "Update configurations"} %>
```

Then, the partial should be:

```
<%= form_for configuration, url: admin_config_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :chars %>
  <%= f.number_field :chars %>
  <%= f.submit submit_text %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively, you could instantiation the `@submit_text` in your controller and leave your partial like:

```
<%= form_for @configuration, url: admin_config_path, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :chars %>
  <%= f.number_field :chars %>
  <%= f.submit @submit_text %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller and call your partial like:

```
<%= render :partial => 'layouts/admin/configuration_form' %>
```

In this case, the partial will use the controller variables rather than locals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it's helping me build my understanding of how rails works. I worked with a tutorial and the explanations were lacking in this area.